# Assigning a a value from one table to unrelated table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables one with existing usernames with columns username,assignedto and date. assigned column is null and another table capturing phonenumber and class. I want when a phone number is captured it can be given a username that is already in username table or I update/record the phonenumber in assigned to column in user_names table. Anyone with an Idea how I can achieve this in Laravel.
My Model Code

```
   Schema::create('user_names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();c
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('userName');
        $table->string('timePackage');
        $table->string('assignedTo');
    });
```

and my phonenumber model

```
    Schema::create('user_names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('phoneNumber');
        $table->string('class');
      
    });
```

Comment: Seems like these tables should be related.

Comment: @El_Vanja. For the purpose I want they are not related. I have an idea in SQL but to convert to laravel is a problem like SELECT * FROM `user_names` limit 1;
update `user_names`  set assignedTo = '072...' where timePackage='2 hrs' ;